# How to modify the data by operation

Tags: mysql

For example,I just want 'a' to be modified to be 'a+1' and I don't need to know the value of 'a'.

I only need to modify the quantity of the articles when the user composes or deletes an article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `update` statement like this

```
update your_table
set some_column = some_column + 1
```

to increment `some_column` for all records.